# Using a switch statement onClick to add a character to a EditText

Tags: java, android, onclick, switch-statement

I am trying to reduce the amount of code I have by making everything more efficient

I want to implement a switch statement instead of a long if statement 
here is the switch i have began creating

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.buttonA:
            displayLetters(v);
            break;
        case R.id.buttonB:
            displayLetters(v);
            break;
```

and here is the displayLetters method that I want each case to run

```
private void displayLetters(View v) {
    NewDisplayWord = EditText.getText().toString();
    NewDisplayWord = NewDisplayWord + v.getTag();
    EditText.setText(NewDisplayWord);
}
```

However instead of displaying A or B in the textedit when I press the buttons, I get null when I press any of the buttons

Comment: "I get null" meaning... the line `v.getId()` is null?

Comment: It definitely has a value in it, it worked 100% with an if statement

Comment: What line of your code gives you null? can you post a stack trace?

Comment: Im not sure what a stack trace is but, when I press a button ... Null is displayed in the text edit, instead of the text that is written on the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's change displayLetters to accept String

```
private void displayLetters(final String letter) {
    newDisplayWord = editText.getText().toString();
    newDisplayWord = newDisplayWord + letter;

    editText.setText(newDisplayWord);
}
```

Then call displayLetters() with String param:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.buttonA:
            displayLetters(v.getTag()); 
            break;
        case R.id.buttonB:
            displayLetters(v.getTag());
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

If your onClick() listener will serve only the buttons, you could probably simplify it even further:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    //cast view to button
    Button bt = (Button) v;

    //get text from button
    final String letter = bt.getText().toString();

    //pass it to displayLetters()
    displayLetters(letter);
}
```

Please follow Java naming convention, that is variable names start with lowercase. Also, I'm assuming that you have properly set your button and editText:

```
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for your help, finally someone with sense. Unfortuntetly Im left with the same issue, I'm after the text of the button not the tag?

Comment: No problem. See modification in the last onClick() listener. Similar logic can also be implemented in the one with switch statement.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are trying to get the text from the `EditText` by doing `EditText.getText()`. I think what you mean to do is use the `v` variable passed into `displayLetters()`. You can do something like this:

```
private void displayLetters(View v) {
    NewDisplayWord = ((EditText)v).getText().toString();
    NewDisplayWord = NewDisplayWord + v.getTag();// I do not know what is the use of `getTag()` here...
    ((EditText)v).setText(NewDisplayWord);
}
```

If the `displayLetters()` will only deal with `EditText`s, you can make its parameter be an `EditText`

Comment: Im trying to get the editText contents, then add on the new letter that has been pressed onto the end of the editText. I am sure getTag is incorrect, but i believe you can't use getText as it cant be used in type view

Comment: That is why I am casting `v` to an `EditText` which has the `getText()`.

Comment: With this I get the error message "EditText Cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: You need to import the class if you haven't done it. If you are using Eclipse press `Ctrl+Shift+O` to organize your imports.

Comment: Cannot cast from View to EditText and The method getText() is undefined for the type EditText

Comment: Are you sure you are spelling `EditText` correctly? on your comment you wrote `EdiText`...

Comment: Yes i am ... Mistake in the comment only

Comment: Try cleaning your project. In Eclipse do Project-->Clean.

Comment: Did you try cleaning your project?

Comment: The error is telling you that it can find the `EditText Class`; it is not the code

Comment: Can you update your question to include the whole class where `displayLetters()` resides? make sure you include the import statements on the update.